# Drawing a circular sector using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

Can someone help me doing this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector#/media/File:Circle_arc.svg

in TikZ? I would really appreciate any help.

I already tried inserting the image into my TeX file but it didn't work no matter what I tried, so I'd love to insert it as a TikZ-drawing.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could convert the svg to pdf and then include it. Drawing it in TikZ wouldn't be too difficult, but you should really show what you attempted. Just asking people to recreate images for you without even sample code showing what you tried doesn't tend to get good results here.

Comment: i provide my tikz-attempts whenever there are some. however, my tikz-skills are purely based on copy&paste from tutorials and trying to making things work but it usually ends up being a big mess and i sit there for hours without any success. in this particular case, i could have barely managed to draw the circle and with some luck the radius r. i dont know if that would have been a big help. thanks for your consideration nonetheless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily\Large]
\draw (0,0) circle (4cm);
\draw[very thick,fill=green!30] (0,0) --  (220:4) arc(220:120:4) -- cycle;
\draw[latex-latex]  (220:1.2) arc(220:120:1.2) node[midway,left]{$\theta$};
\draw[latex-latex]  (220:4.5) arc(220:120:4.5) node[midway,left]{L};
\draw (120:4) -- (120:4.5) (220:4) -- (220:4.5);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) --  (20:4) node[midway,above]{r};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hello marmot, thank you very much! highly  appreciating your effort and time

Comment: `L` and `r` are math quantities, they should be `$L$` and `$r$`, I think.

Comment: @Kpym I only wanted to provide a rather close reproduction of the linked picture.

Comment: @marmot If you really want this you should use `$\mathrm{L}$` and `$\mathrm{r}$`.

Comment: @Kpym If you ask me how I would label the distances, I would certainly use math mode. But this is not important here, I just tried to reproduce the OP's picture.

Comment: @marmot this is precisely what I'm saying in my second comment : the OP picture use `$\mathrm{L}$` and `$\mathrm{r}$` (the font is serif font, and not like in your picture).

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={[inset=0,angle'=27]Stealth}]
\draw circle(2);
\draw [thick,fill=cyan!20](230:2)--(0,0)--(130:2) arc (130:230:2)--cycle;
\draw [->](0,0)--node[above]{$r$} (10:2);
\draw [|<->|](130:2.3) arc (130:230:2.3) node[left,pos=.5]{$L$};
\draw [<->]  (130:1)   arc (130:230:1)   node[left,pos=.5]{$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]